# Is this a tuple? minimum (1,10)

Tags: haskell

Why it always return the second element?

```
λ> minimum (1, 10)
10
it :: (Ord a, Num a) => a
λ> minimum (10, 1)
1
it :: (Ord a, Num a) => a
```

Also

```
λ> minimum (1, True)
True
it :: Bool
λ> minimum (True, 1)
1
it :: (Ord a, Num a) => a
```

If it is a tuple, why it return the second element?
If not, why?

Comment: The question I suggested talks about `length`, but the underlying issue is the same. Both `length` and `minimum` are methods of the `Foldable` class, and the behaviour you describe arises from the `Foldable` instance for 2-tuples (and yes, `(1, 10)` is indeed a tuple).

Comment: (By the way, it is worth noting that, in your second example, obtaining `minimum (1, True)` could not possibly involve comparing `1` and `True`, as they have different types. danidiaz makes a similar point in his answer to the other question.)

Comment: @duplode Thanks, it help me a lot. Now, I know how it works.         : D